# Sanity's urlFor not working with my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I'm following a tutorial and started running into an issue where my react site goes blank after I connected it to my sanity backend. I think I figured out the problem is coming from the urlFor function by commenting lines out to see which line causes the issue. But now I have no clue how to solve the issue.

Here's the file where the problem occurs.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import './About.scss';
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';

const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';

    client.fetch(query).then((data) => {
      setAbouts(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">I Know that <span>Good Design</span> <br />means  <span>Good Business</span></h2>

      <div className="app__profiles">
        {abouts.map((about, index) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: 'tween' }}
            className="app__profile-item"
            key={about.title + index}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
            <h2 className="bold-text" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{about.title}</h2>
            <p className="p-text" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>{about.description}</p>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default About
```

It seems like the problem line is:

```
<img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
```

Here's my client

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-02-01',
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, used this

```
import React from 'react'
import client from './sanityClient'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'

// Get a pre-configured url-builder from your sanity client
const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client)

// Then we like to make a simple function like this that gives the
// builder an image and returns the builder for you to specify additional
// parameters:
function urlFor(source) {
  return builder.image(source)
}
```

Took from here https://www.sanity.io/docs/presenting-images